# How to move programmatically to selected row in Qt?

Tags: qt, qtreeview, qmodelindex

I use QTreeView and QSortFilterProxyModel

```
// Here I determine the index, that was saved before (_lastAddObjectIndex - QModelIndex)
QModelIndex next_index = _proxyModel->index(_lastAddObjectIndex.row(), 0);
    
// Here I select the row programmatically, and after that I'd like to move to that row (because table might have many rows)
view->selectionModel()->select(next_index, QItemSelectionModel::ClearAndSelect | QItemSelectionModel::Rows | QItemSelectionModel::SelectCurrent);
```

Comment: Maybe `QAbstractItemView::scrollTo()` function would be useful for that? I.e. `view->scrollTo(next_index);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by moving, you mean scrolling. If so, you can achieve this by using [this API](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qabstractitemview.html#scrollTo):

```
view->scrollTo(next_index);
```

You can even change the scroll hint if you pass a second parameter to the method. This depends on whether you are happy with the default value, which just makes sure that the item is visible.

You can refer to the [documentation](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qabstractitemview.html#scrollTo) for fine-tuning this behaviour further in case you need to.